# How to show that $\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sqrt{1 + \cos^2 x}}dx$ not solvable in closed form (or is it?).

Tags: calculus

In my Calculus book I read that $\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sqrt{1 + \cos^2 x}}\ dx$ is not solvable in closed form by any of the methods in the book.

In general how does one show that such an integral is not solvable except by a numerical method? Or are there advanced ways in which it can be done?

Comment: It is "not solvable in closed form by **any of the methods in the book**". The solution involves elliptic integrals. Just wait for them ! Cheers

Comment: It clearly says "by any of the methods in the book". The solution includes an elliptic integral of the second kind. The closed form would be $$2 \sqrt2 E\left (\frac12 \right )$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the tangent half angle substitution, the integral is "simply":
$$2\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+t^4}}{(1+t^2)^2}\,dt = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\left(\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2+4\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^2\right)=2\sqrt{2}\cdot E\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
where $E(\cdot)$ is the [complete elliptic integral of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html).

Comment: This is currently above my head so far as acceptance from a position of (my) knowing it is correct - I'm going to accept it anyway under the assumption that it is.